# Generating a correct Acestream Link from an HTTP .m3u8 URL

Tags: streaming, p2p

Given an http:// URL pointing to an acestream stream like this

`http://127.0.0.1:6878/ace/m/XXXXXXXc36f88ef70de865b884dea087789e302b/6f1da80ef2aec1b68522d533480c476d.m3u8`

(where I have replaced some characters by XXX), what's the corresponding acestream:// link?

I was assuming that the acestream ID would be
`XXXXXXXc36f88ef70de865b884dea087789e302b`
so I tried to generate an acestream:// link like:
`acestream://XXXXXXXc36f88ef70de865b884dea087789e302b`

But the link with http:// protocol is working in Ace Player and the link with the acestream:// protocol is NOT.

In fact, I've started to suspect that the filename of the m3u8 (6f1da80ef2aec1b68522d533480c476d.m3u8) is not a random string but something that I should parse alongside the XXXXXXXc36f88ef70de865b884dea087789e302b part to generate a correct acestream ID. Any link to some kind of documentation about how to parse those IDs will be greatly appreciated.